# Split a row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my DB, there are 2 tables ie `RateCalendar` & `Blackout`.

`Ratecalendar` stores daily, weekly, etc. rates between 2 dates for a Car Class. eg

From 10Jan to 27 May 2016, Daily rates are say £20,
weekly rates are £50 and so on.

Similarly, for other Dates range daily weekly rates are specified.

Suppose for 2 days (4May to 5May) I blackout my car ie car won't be available for a location. Now, I have to show the record as splitted ie from  10Jan to 3May, Cars will be available ie `IsAvailable->True`.

From 4th May to 5th May as Blackout (ie `IsAvailable->False`) and 
from 6th till 29May again cars will be available.

All records will not split. Only those Cars whose details are present in blackout will split.

Moreover, depending on Blackout dates, splitting will be done. For eg. in blackout if there are two records for a car ie car is blacked out for say 10Jan to 12Jan And 4th May to 5th May, then, output will be like:

```
Car   StartDate        EndDate             Available
Car1  10Jan2016 12:00  12Jan2016 1:00      N
Car1  12Jan2016 1:00   4May2016 9:00       Y
Car1  4May2016  9:00   5May2016 12:00      N
Car1  5May2016 12:00   27May2016 12:00     Y
Car2  10Jan2016 10:00  27May2016 12:00     Y
```

So, row can be splitted into 0 or 2 or multiple depending on Blackout dates for car.

What's the best way to do this?

Below is the layout of
1) RateCalendar Table(there are 2 more fields AgencyId,LocationId as shown in Blackout Table)

```
RateCalId RateGroupId CarClassId StartDate        EndDate        DailyRate
  1         1            1       10Jan2016 10:00  26May2016 11:00   20
  2         1            1       27May2016 11:00  28June2016 12:00  40
```

2) Blackout Table

```
BlackoutId AgencyId LocationId BeginDate         EndDate
   1         1        1        10Jan2016 12:00 12Jan2016 1:00
   2         1        1        4May2016  9:00   5May2016 12:00
```

3) BlackoutCars

```
BlackoutId CarId
  1         1
  1         2
  2         1
  2         2
```

4) BlackoutRateGroup

```
BlackoutId RategroupId
 1           1
 1           0(0=>all)
 2           3
```

Comment: its better to include your current sql query.

Comment: Also include the query that identifies the records that need be split. Then you just use `CROSS JOIN` on that to split them

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data (preferably as DDL + DML statements), your current sql statement and it's results.